# how to input letters and numbers using joptionpane

Tags: java, swing

I want to input something like: number23 using **JOptionPane**, but all I know how to do is either input a number or input a string.
 How do I input word + number?

What I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class morePractice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str;
        int num1;
        int total=0;
        char letter;

        str=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter phrase");

        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
            letter=str.charAt(i);
            if(letter>='A'&&letter<='Z'){
                total++;
            }

        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There are " + total + " upper case letters");

    }

}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783836/joptionpane-and-reading-integers-beginner-java/14784096#14784096)

Answer (score 0):

Use Regular Expression
Try this approach

```
String s = "Number23";
System.out.print(s.replaceAll("[^0-9]",""));
```

it gives you just a number

or `s.replaceAll("[^a-z]","")`  gives you just characters

Comment: Ah thank you! I didn't even know you could do strings like that. Thanks alot!

Comment: @broception: Please accept the answer, ream about this at [***`stackoverflow.com/about`***](http://stackoverflow.com/about)