# Convert string to double in a dialog box

Tags: java, swing, parsing, methods, joptionpane

I need help to understand the code.

```
public class ComputeLoanUsingInputDialog{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String annulInterestRateString = JOptionPane.ShowInputDialog("Enter annual interest rate:")

        // convert string to double
        double annualInterestRate = Double.parseDouble(annualInterestRateString);

        //Obtain monthly interest rate
        double monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate/1200;

        .....
    }
}
```

So my question is if you have a dialog box pop out to ask user to insert a number then why do you need to use parse method to convert the variable from string to double?

Comment: Because all input in java is in the form of a `String`

Comment: There's a lot of different ways to achieve what you want.  You could take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783836/joptionpane-and-reading-integers-beginner-java/14784096#14784096) for some ideas..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Java accepts the input as a `String` - it doesn't that what it's getting is a `double` until you tell it to parse that `String` into a double.

Comment: This is my first time here posting, didn't aware of the format, thank you for fixing it for me

Comment: Thank you drewmore, I appreciated your help and I am glad that I came here, it helps a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Because it's much easier to manipulate a double mathematically than it is a string.

You get an annual interest from the dialog box as a string, you can see this from the [online documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog%28java.lang.Object%29) (all but one returns a `String`, the one that returns an `Object` doesn't match your function signature).

However, you can't really do much with that other than string-type operations.

If you want to manipulate it mathematically (such as dividing it by twelve hundred in your case), it needs to be converted into a numeric type of some description.

Now you *could* modify `JOptionPane` to provide:

```
double JOptionPane.ShowInputDialogGetDouble (...);
```

but that introduces a large amount of new code (one per type) with lots of extra error checking that is, honestly, unnecessary since you can do it quite easily with your current method, `Double.parseDouble()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()` returns `String`, since the user is free to type non-digit characters in the text field.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciated your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane returns a String object as it's return value

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component, java.lang.Object)

(Can't get the url to show up as a single link, you'll have to copy the whole thing.

If the return type was double, you wouldn't have to parse it.